# MYSQL summation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

We need to calculate carbon footprint for each product we are given. Carbon footprint is basically the sum of the product of carbon foot print of each element with the percentage of each element that composes a given product. 
The following code is what we have so far but it's not working, we also tried to use SUM(e.carbonfootPrint * c.percentage/100)

```
SELECT p.name, e.carbonfootPrint * c.percentage/100 AS CarbonFootprintProdut
FROM Produt p, Element e, composed c, Brand b
WHERE p.tipo = 'lar'
    AND c.produt = p.code
    AND c.ProdBrand = m.number
    AND c.element = e.code;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT p.name,
       SUM(e.carbonfootPrint * c.percentage)/100 AS CarbonFootprintProdut
FROM Produt p JOIN
     Element e
     ON c.element = e.code JOIN
     composed c
     ON c.produt = p.code
WHERE p.tipo = 'lar'
GROUP BY p.name;
```

Notes:

- The `brand` table isn't used, so I removed it.
- You need to aggregate the product, so you get the total for the entire product.
- You need a `GROUP BY`.
- Use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: it still doesn't work, it returns the same values for all products when we should have different ones

Comment: @gabrielascm . . . This should return a different value on each row in the result set, unless the data is the same for each product.